# Overwrite Laravel Http Faker

Tags: laravel, http, phpunit, laravel-8

Is there a way to overwrite values of `Http::fake([])` in Laravel during testing. I've noticed that if I set a value during a faker, eg. `Http::fake(['url1.com' => Http::response('OK'), 'url2.com' => Http::response('Not Found', 404),])`, if for some reason I need to change the value of say `url1.com` to something else such as `['message' => 'Success']`, if I "update" the value by calling `Http::fake(['url1.com' => Http::response(['message' => 'Success'])` again at a later point, I'd expect the response when I call `Http::get('url1.com')` to return `['message' => 'Success']` but it instead always returns `OK` which was the original value set.

Same way if I later call `Http::fake(['url2.com' => Http::response(['message' => 'Object found.'])])`, I would expect the response when I call `Http::get('url2.com')` to be `['message' => 'Object found.']` but it'll always return `Not found` which was the original value set.

Comment: Following @Healyhatman answer, I added this function to my base TestCase class ```protected function clearExistingFakes(): static
{
    $reflection = new \ReflectionObject(Http::getFacadeRoot());
    $property = $reflection->getProperty('stubCallbacks');
    $property->setAccessible(true);
    $property->setValue(Http::getFacadeRoot(), collect());

    return $this;
}``` that ensures I can call `self::clearExistingFakes();` in any test class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ferhsom's answer worked for me in Laravel 8.x but not in Laravel 9.x, where I had to use the answer from https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/how-to-delete-instance-of-httpfake-in-app

I added the following method to the base TestCase class

```
protected function clearExistingFakes(): static
{
    $reflection = new \ReflectionObject(Http::getFacadeRoot());
    $property = $reflection->getProperty('stubCallbacks');
    $property->setAccessible(true);
    $property->setValue(Http::getFacadeRoot(), collect());

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Also work's in Laravel 10!

Comment: Yeah work's in Laravel 10, how complicated it is :(

Answer (score 4):

You can use achieve this by swapping the Http client

```
Http::fake(['https://potato.com' => Http::response('Yummy!', 200)]);

dump(Http::get('https://potato.com')->body()); // Yummy!
```

at some point in your test, you can reset the Http Facade using Facade Swap

```
Http::swap(app(\Illuminate\Http\Client\Factory::class));
```

now you can change the fake value to whatever you want

```
Http::fake(['https://potato.com' => Http::response("That's what the dcotor ordered.", 200)]);

dump(Http::get('https://potato.com')->body()); // That's what the doctor orderd.
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
// Added this before doing the Http::fake()
$realHttp = app(\Illuminate\Http\Client\Factory::class);

// Added this when I needed to reset it.
Http::swap($realHttp);
```

Worked fine after doing this. This is on Laravel 10.x

Comment: This doesn't work in laravel 10